# Implement Interface Generic Function

Tags: c#, generics

I have this function in my service which uses a generic type so I don't have to reference another project in this project.

```
async Task<string> EagerLoadAllAsync<T>(
   params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) where T : class;
```

When I implement this in my concrete class can I just do this (or something similar):

```
async Task<string> EagerLoadAllAsync<Lead>(
   params Expression<Func<Lead, object>>[] includeProperties);
```

It doesn't matter to me too much, I just wanted to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because your overridden method would not be able to deal with all possible `T`. It could only work on a `Lead`. This endangers type safety and is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

As usr answered, no, it is not possible directly.

However, depending on your specific needs, it may be possible in a way that will be satisfactory for your needs.

Right now, your interface (which I'm guessing is an abstract class, but that doesn't really matter for the purposes of this answer) is defined as

```
abstract class C {
  async Task<string> EagerLoadAllAsync<T>(
     params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) where T : class
  { ... }
}
```

Instead, your interface could be a generic *type* with a non-generic *method*:

```
abstract class C<T> where T : class {
  async Task<string> EagerLoadAllAsync(
     params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
  { ... }
}
```

And your derived class would derive from `C<Lead>` instead of `C`.

However, this does require modifying all users of `C` to account for the fact that it is now a generic type.

Comment: Actually, having looked at your answer, I could indeed do that, at the moment I have a generic repository that I use in different services, so I could make a generic service interface for all my services to implement. That would save a lot of writing. Thanks :)